# How to use a string in My.Settings VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, settings

```
For Each i In web
    web(i) = My.Settings.sweb(i)
    name(i) = My.Settings.sname(i)
Next
```

This code doesn't work, it is what I want to do. How do I make it so that I can change the name in `my.settings` without hard coding it?
Basically I want to be able to change the name of the input to `my.settings`

How can I make the "sweb" part of My.Setting a variable so I can change it.

Comment: I'm still not completely clear on what you are trying to ask here, can you put in a more detailed example?

Comment: Is `My.Settings.sweb` an array of strings?

Comment: @Jonsca No, They are the name of my settings that i already have set up. e.g. sweb1, sweb2 (the "s" means save)

Comment: What kind of object is web?  is sweb?  If you've already set them up, why do they need to be changed?

Comment: @Jonsca sweb is a settings string that is set up. I have swed1, sweb2, sweb3 all the way to 10. I was to save all the variable into these

Comment: Ah, okay, now I see.  Well, couldn't you make all of your settings into an array of strings `My.Settings.swed(10)` so you could step through them like you propose.  Otherwise, it's really not possible, because you can't assemble the variable names out of strings at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
For Each i In web
    web(i) = My.Settings("sweb" & i)
    name(i) = My.Settings("sname" & i)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are wanting to access your system settings like an array. If you are wanting to iterate through it I would suggest something like;

```
 Dim myArray() As String = {My.Settings.sweb1, My.Settings.sweb2, My.Settings.sweb3}
```

Then you can do:

```
For Each i in web
      web(i) = myArray(i)
      ...
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you make all of your settings into an array of strings `My.Settings.swed(10)` so you could step through them like you propose.

I'm not sure the `For Each` loop is correct.

```
 Dim My.Settings.swed(10) As String

 For i = My.Settings.swed.LBound To My.Settings.swed.UBound
    web(i) = My.Settings.swed(i)
 Next
```

When you have a `For Each` it's usually over each member of a collection